# Porting Windows Phone app to Android

Tags: c#, java, android, windows-phone, porting

Can anyone tell me how can I port a Windows Phone app to Android? Links to guides/tutorials would be very much appreciated since I cannot find them through Google.

Comment: You could try [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to check out [xamarin.com](http://www.xamarin.com) as they allow you to run C# on Android and iPhone. They have VERY good documentation [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/)